# Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions config file don't make file

Tags: nginx, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

Platform: java8(not tomcat, because I use spring-boot, so I use embedded tomcat)

so I zipped by below command

`zip -r app.zip app.jar .ebextensions`

.ebextensions contain test.config file.
`files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/test.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 10M;`

I check each ec2 instance, but don't make /etc/nginx/conf.d/test.conf
and I check /var/log/eb-activity.log
`[2017-10-15T05:12:32.538Z] INFO  [2995]  - [Application deployment prod-map-api-c0c8a00b590c593700ba85405010a85bea21ecd2@26/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Starting activity...
[2017-10-15T05:12:32.538Z] INFO  [2995]  - [Application deployment prod-map-api-c0c8a00b590c593700ba85405010a85bea21ecd2@26/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_configure_application.sh] : Starting activity...
[2017-10-15T05:12:33.164Z] INFO  [2995]  - [Application deployment prod-map-api-c0c8a00b590c593700ba85405010a85bea21ecd2@26/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_configure_application.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Executing: /usr/bin/unzip -o -d /var/app/staging /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  Archive:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
    inflating: /var/app/staging/map.jar
    inflating: /var/app/staging/Procfile
     creating: /var/app/staging/.ebextensions/
    inflating: /var/app/staging/.ebextensions/test.config
  Executing: HOME=/tmp /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/ruby /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/foreman export supervisord --procfile /var/app/staging/Procfile --root /var/app/current --app application --log /var/log/ --user webapp --template /opt/elasticbeanstalk/private/config/foreman/supervisord --env /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/elasticbeanstalk.env /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/supervisor
  [foreman export] writing: application.conf
  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/log-conf -n supervisor -l'/var/log/supervisord.log' -t bundlelogs
  Executing: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/log-conf -n containerlistener -l'/var/log/eb-container-listener.log' -t bundlelogs`

I can't find any fail message...

Answer (score 0):

Standby counsel

JAVA SE's proxy configuration is different from other platforms.
Please see [Configuring the Reverse Proxy in JAVA SE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html)

And maybe I don't have write file permission in /etc/nginx/conf.d
I tried to make some file in /home/ec2-user with *.config file, It works.

It is my mistake not to read official documents.